# How can I use different rules in Makefile for two groups of files?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have one Makefile to build an executable and a library. Executable consists of a lot of source files and library consists of one .cpp file. The difference between compilation of executable and library is -fPIC option.

There is a compilation rule:

```
%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

all: $(TARGET) $(TARGET_LIB)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(TARGET_LIB): $(LIBOBJS)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^
```

I tried to add compilation rule for library and got this:

```
lib.o : lib.cpp
        $(CXX) -fPIC -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

all: $(TARGET) $(TARGET_LIB)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(TARGET_LIB): $(LIBOBJS)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^
```

Unfortunately, only lib is compiled in this case. Second rule is omitted.

How can I use a rule for one file and different rule for group of other files?

Comment: "Unfortunately, only lib is compiled in this case." This depends of the rest of your Makefile which is not shown here. So we can't tell you anything as the rest is simply missing.

Comment: @alistair - How do you invoke the Makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just run `make` without a target, the *first* target gets built. So just put `all` back at the top and it should work fine.